# MVC MultiSelect modelbinding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

i want to be able to display and update my User's Organisations preferably using the htmlhelper Html.TextBoxFor(

I have an entityframework 5 database first database with relationships defined as expected on the 3 tables 
User
Organisation
UserOrganisation

which yield the classes below

```
public partial class User
{
    public System.Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
    ...
}
public partial class Organisation
{
    public int OrganisationID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    ...
}
public partial class UserOrganisation
{
    public System.Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public int OrganisationID { get; set; }
}
```

I pass in the user as the model and also populate a list of potential organisations in the viewbag i.e.

```
ViewBag.PossibleOrganisations = OrganisationFactories.GetOrganisations()
```

and the razor markup is.
      @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.UserOrganisations,
                new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.PossibleOrganisations,"OrganisationID","Title"))

Now this displays the list of Organisations correctly and i can multiselect them. But it doesn't show the selected Organisations, and it also wont write this back to the database when posting back (incidentally all other fields did write back prior to this change).

Does anyone have any suggestions or examples of a multiselect list working in this fashion?

Cheers
Tim